# URL not updating under update panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

Thanks for your reply. When I click on 'click it first' link, the browser URL change. Where as I click on the second link it also update the URL in browser, but if I click on the "update button" which I have put in update panel, it post back some server function.

After that if I click on any of the link button the update URL functionality does not work.

Do u have any idea to reinitialize jQuery code after the update panel function?

I know that when we use jQuery with update panel, then we have to reinitialize it on every page load, but I am not able to find the correct jQuery function of that jQuery plugin to call on asp.net page load event.

Here is the link of that jQuery plugin

http://code.google.com/p/news21-berkeley/source/browse/branches/v2011/js/jquery.address-1.4.min.js?spec=svn671&r=671

```
//Page Updating.aspx

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UpdatingUrl.aspx.cs" Inherits="UpdateUrl.UpdatingUrl" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.address-1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table class="style1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" rel="address:/section/?id=1&amp;name=Ravindra nofollow">Click it first</a>
                    </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="UpdateButton1" OnClick="UpdateButton_Click" Text="Update" />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="DateTimeLabel1" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" rel="address:/section/?id=2&amp;name=Chauhan nofollow">Click it after Update
                        Button click</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//UpdatingUrl.aspx.cs Page

    protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTimeLabel1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need _endRequest, _beginRequest Handlers. In code behind add this.

```
public object endRequestHandle { get; set; }

public object beginRequestHandle { get; set; }
```

In your aspx page, add this:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandle);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandle);
        function beginRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
           //call any function if you want before Ajax update/request begins
        }

        function endRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
         $.getScript("jquery.address-1.4.min.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr){});
        }
```

Now, it will work, the script will be reloaded and executed. More on $.getScript() [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: I think you're on the right track Leta, but looking at the question's sample code; it doesn't look like the address plugin is triggered manually, instead it's activated automatically via parsing the rel attribute. You'll probably want to add to your answer, that in the endRequestHandle javascript they'll also need to trigger the address plugin manually.

Comment: Oops, didn't see that, @chouhan_ravi5 edited the answer, hope it works

Comment: Cool, I wonder if jquery.address has a way of doing a manual trigger?